# java write to file results in chinese letters

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, utf, file-writing

I'm decrypting a regular text file and encountering an issue I cant solve,
My code works like this,
I receive a txt file with letters,numbers and the signs + and / (which is Radix64)
I then read 12 chars from the file, convert them into a string, and then using base64.decoder to decode the text into an 8 byte array.
Using system.out.print on both the byte array and on the string I build shows me that the reading was correct and I got what I needed from the file.
Now I shift the bytes a few times to the right or left and want to write the byte array to a new file which is the decrypted message.

I'm using FileOutputStream to write to a new file, now comes the problem, I open the file and its all Chinese letters.

I have no clue how is that even possible since the only thing I do is write bytes to a file.
I tried to find information regarding this subject without any success, only related topic was python/ruby related and was stating that its a UTF-8/UTF-16 problem but no answers to how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated, and if posting parts of my code will help please let me know what exactly is needed.

```
private static void Decryption() {
        InputStream byteReader = null;
        FileOutputStream fop = null;
        int byteByByte = 0;
        char[] radixToByte = new char[12];
        byte[] block = new byte[8];
        byte[] decryptedBlock = new byte[8];
        long key = 0;

        //the file which will contain the plain text will be p.txt in the same directory c.txt is
        try {
            fop = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-5)+"p.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File was not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //open key file and read the key.
        try {
            byteReader = new FileInputStream(keyFileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File was not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //reading 56 bits in radix format and building the key accordingly
        char[] keyByteArray = new char[12];
        for(int k = 0; k < 12; k++){
            try {
                byteByByte = byteReader.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            keyByteArray[k] = (char) byteByByte;
        }
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] decodedByteArray = decoder.decode(new String(keyByteArray));
        for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++){
            key <<= 8;
            key |= (decodedByteArray[k] & 0x00000000000000FF);
        }

        //open cipher text to decrypt.
        try {
            byteReader = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File was not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //while haven't reached end of cipher text message keep reading byte by byte and decrypting
        //them block by block (each block 64 bits).
        while(isFileReadingFinished == false){  
            for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
                try {
                    byteByByte = byteReader.read();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(byteByByte == -1){
                    isFileReadingFinished = true;
                    break;
                }
                radixToByte[i] = (char)byteByByte;
            }

            //this is the block after radix but still decrypted so we will save it for CBC
            block = decoder.decode(new String(radixToByte));

            //encrypt via feistel
            decryptedBlock = feistel(block, key);

            //after decryption we still need to xor with previous encrypted data or IV.
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                decryptedBlock[i] = (byte) (decryptedBlock[i] ^ initializationVector[i]);
            }

            //next decrypted text will need to be xored with the current encrypted text after decryption.
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                initializationVector[i] = block[i];
            }
            try {
                fop.write(decryptedBlock);
                fop.flush();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            fop.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you open the file with?

Comment: can you give us a binary data sample and what the text should be?

Comment: the code that saves the file would probably help.

Comment: uploaded the part that gives me trouble, sadly I cant upload the picture but if I add a system.out.print on on the decrypted block right before I write it to file I get 11011000
11001100
11100001
10001011
11100001
10001011
11100001
10001011
10100000
10000111
10100010
10011011
10100110

Comment: which should just write letters on the file as far as I know

Comment: none of those values map to ascii characters. for ascii/latin you would expect to msb to be 0

Comment: oh my god I'm a complete idiot. thank you A MILION times !